Word VBA using InsertBefore to insert a Continuous Section break
I am trying to use VBA to Insert a Continuous Section Break before a given title (Data_Start) in this case. I currently have the following code:
Sub PageBeforeDataStart()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
With r.Find
Do While .Execute(FindText:="Data_Start", _
Forward:=True) = True
r.InsertBefore (Chr(12))
r.Collapse 0
Loop
End With
End Sub

r.InsertBefore (Chr(12)) is correctly inserting a page break, however I would like it to instead insert a Continuous Section Break. I have tried various version of Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous and there seems to be no VBA Constant for a Continuous break? What am I missing? Thankyou

Why do you need to insert a section break? Section breaks should only ever be inserted because a change to the page layout is required.

I am approaching the isssue I was having yesterday from a different angle as each solution was causing different/new errors. I currently have a working bit of code that separates out the document into separate files based on continuous section breaks (works perfectly) - now I am looking to automate the addition of those section breaks to save users having to do it manually

I’ll take a look at your issues tomorrow when I am back at my computer, but I did notice that you had made some ill advised changes to the code I gave you.

Inserting unnecessary section breaks, especially continuous breaks, not only leads to a more complex document, it also makes it more likely that it will become corrupt.

I really do appreciate the help!

Have you tried range.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous?

Good Morning, I have yes - when I run it with that line it goes into an endless loading loop/crashes VBA
